# How to change opacity with ngstyle?

Tags: angularjs

I have in controller so far:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
```

Now, without any additional code (**method**) in controller I want to set opacity `0.4` on image when  `currentPage ==0`

So I wrote:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
  <div class="pagination no-margin ">
    <ul>
      <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
         <a href=""
          ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
             <i class="icon-fast-backward"
             ng-style="{opacity : (currentPage == 0)?'0.4':'1'}">
             </i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I get error:

```
Unexpected next character  at columns 29-29 [?] in expression [{opacity : (currentPage == 0)?'0.4':'1'}]
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/855/)</kbd>

Do I miss something?

Thank you,

**[EDIT]**

I can write `ng-style="myOpacity"`

and in controller:

```
$scope.myOpacity = {
    'opacity': ($scope.currentPage == 0)?0.4:1
};
```

But it demands additional code in controller

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update**: Since version 1.1.5, Angular does have support for ternary operator in templates.

Angular does not have support for the ternary operator in templates. You can, however, use the poor man's ternary operator:

```html
 ng-style="{opacity : ((currentPage == 0) && '0.4') || '1'}">
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked :) Sorry, can't vote up, must >15 reputation

Answer (score 33):

Actually, AngularJS 1.1.5 has ternary operator (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b) so if you use a version >= 1.1.5 you should be able to use:

```
ng-style="{'opacity' : currentPage == 0 ? 0.4 : 1}"
```

Comment: This helped me a ton! Thanks!